# retrieve username according to his current ip address SQL

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

i am trying to `Select` username based on his login ip address that stored when he logged,

i have two tables

1. users
2. sessions

here is my sql statement

```
Select users.username from users,sessions where user_id = se_user AND se_ip = '" + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress + "';
```

i am using this sql statement inside a `DetailsView` on the `DataSource Configurations`, but it seems it doesn't work

what is the problem ?

Comment: sonded to me like a MS certification exam question ;-). Did you try to run the SQL query manually with a sample IP? Did you try to debug point and see what the value of `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` is?

Comment: What database engine are you using?, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc...

Comment: "Doesn't Work" doesn't provide any kind of starting point for the SO users to help you solve your issue.  What doesn't work?  Are you getting any results?  Is it compiling?  Is the UserHostAddress blank?

Comment: @shoban no its not a MS certification exam question, i am trying to learn c# and sql by doing a small project locally, when i run the page the DetailsView doesn't appear , so no error but no result AND yes i used the same command to insert the current ip

Comment: :-) Did you try what I posted in comment? Manually? Trace point? Anything?

Comment: @Lamak i am sorry , SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: @Bader - What is the result of HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress have you confirmed that it is in the correct format?

Comment: @George , sorry for not clearing the problem , when i run the page , the DetailsView doesn't Appear on the page , so i think it means no returned values from the database

Comment: @ Ramhound , the result when i used this command to insert the ip address , it was my local ip which is 127.0.0.1

Comment: So you are saying the result of HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress was "127.0.0.1" without the quotes, correct?  I assume you have a session in the database with your username and ip address of "127.0.0.1" have you tried to play around with the select statement ( crude I forgot the tool ) but it allows you to view the database and write queries similar to the feature in Visual Studio ( except its actually useful ).

Answer (score 3):

Well, for starters, you should use a proper JOIN instead of the old version. 
And it looks like you are comparing se_ip with the same string all the time. If you are defining that statement in C#, i think you have a problem with the your quotes. In SQL simple quotes `'` define a string, in C# doble quotes `"` define a string. So in C# yo should define your query like this:

```
"Select users.username 
from users JOIN [sessions] 
ON users.[USER_ID] = [sessions].se_user 
where se_ip = '" + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress + '"
```

Comment: still no values , i want to note that when i stored the ip address , i stored se_ip  VARCHAR , does that make any difference ?

Comment: it shouldn't make any difference, can you see int the SQL Server profiler what query you are actually executing?

Comment: i tried to run the sql code wrote but in the SQL SERVER but i changed the value of se_ip "Select users.username 
from users JOIN [sessions] 
ON users.[USER_ID] = [sessions].se_user 
where se_ip = CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address'); , still no values returned ...

Comment: I meant that with SQL Server Profiler you can monitor every query executed in the server, so you should try to execute your C# code and watch what sql statement was used.

Comment: i am using SQL Server Express , i followed MSDN to know how to open it but there is no such thing ,

Comment: Yeah, SQL Server Express doesn't have a Profiler. But in http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/ there's a free one you can use.

Answer (score 2):

I would be careful with using the IP address since most users from home or inside an office have a dynamic IP address assigned.  For a period of time it will most likely be the same, but if they happen to get a new address (modem reset, offline for a period of time, etc) then you can no longer trust that IP address.

I'm assuming you are already incorporating that, but just in case anyone comes along and decides to use this idea, they should know that.

Comment: yes i know the ip address changes every 7 days i think depending on the DHCP setting , but here in my example i am talking about the method in general , thanks :)